# Rmarkdown - Run code and display errors in document

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I get an error message when running the code below which is expected - I would like this to be ran and displayed in the pdf, however the error is returned in r and the code doesn't run.

`{r, warning=TRUE}
library(survey)
debug(withReplicates.svyrep.design)`

I have tried `warning=TRUE` but this doesn't work.

How can I get the error displayed in the document?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add `error=TRUE` to the chunk options. That will result in the script running to completion with the error appearing in the output.