# Get error messages from R displayed as they natively appear in an R session using knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to build an html document using Rmarkdown in which error messages from R can be displayed as they do natively appear in an R interactive session.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34137797/1878788) is similar, but doesn't have the requirement that  error messages appear exactly as in an interactive session: I tried using `error=TRUE` for a given chunk, at the error gets prefixed with `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos):`:

With the following chunk:

````
```{r, error=TRUE}
notexistingvariable
```
````

I expect:

```
Error: object 'notexistingvariable' not found
```

I get:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'notexistingvariable' not found
```

I tried adding the `results="asis"` option, but this has no effect here. I think this only applies to non-error output.

---

#### Attempt at using `wrap.error`

As suggested [in the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257445/1878788), I tried to set a custom `wrap.error` function.

`test.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

wrap.error <- function(x, options) {
  # x is an error object, with components "call" and "message".  Ignore
  # the call, but wrap the result like code:
  paste0("```\n## Error: ", x$message, "\n```")
}
```

```{r, error=TRUE}
notexistingvariable
```
````

Conversion to html:

```
$ R -e "rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd',output_file='test.html')"

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd',output_file='test.html')


processing file: test.Rmd
  |................                                                 |  25%
  ordinary text without R code

  |................................                                 |  50%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.................................................                |  75%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ error: logi TRUE


output file: test.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /home/bli/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /tmp/RtmpAoBtc7/rmarkdown-str53186fa5c04d.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' 

Output created: test.html
> 
>
```

The `test.html` file looks as follows:

[image: html rendering by firefox]

---

Using `wrap.simpleError`, as the updated answer now proposes, works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Updated to reflect R 3.5.x changes)

You can set custom renderers for the output (see `vignette("knit_print")`), but I think they are not called when an error occurs.  The generic `wrap()` function is called in that case. `knitr` defines a `wrap.error()` method, and prior to R 3.5.0, that could be overridden by a user.  However, in the latest release of R, methods defined in a package are chosen in preference to those defined by the user, so it no longer works.

However, there is still a solution for some errors.  For the example in the question, the error object that is created has class `c("simpleError", "error", "condition")`, and `knitr` doesn't define a `wrap.simpleError()` method.  You can define one, and override its handling.

You do it like this:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

wrap.simpleError <- function(x, options) {
  # x is an error object, with components "call" and "message".  Ignore
  # the call, but wrap the result like code:
  paste0("```\n## Error: ", x$message, "\n```")
}
```

```{r, error=TRUE}
notexistingvariable
```
````

This displays the result like this:
[image]

There's also an output hook to handle errors:  see https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/.  However, it seems to be called after `wrap.error`, when the message is already formed.  You could edit that message to delete
the parts you don't want using code like this:

````
```{r}   
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) {
  paste0("```\n", 
         sub(" in eval(expr, envir, enclos)", "", x, fixed = TRUE),
         "\n```")
})
```e
````

This may be more robust than the `wrap.simpleError` approach, which 
would stop working if `knitr` ever defined a `wrap.simpleError` method like that.  It will also handle all errors, not just `"simpleError"` ones. It has the 
disadvantage that it is probably harder to customize it to handle different types of errors, and might not work in different locales where "Error in" is translated to some other language.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't seem to have effects in my document. I also tried in a minimal Rmakrdown document, and I still get the `eval(expr, envir, enclos)` in the error message.

Comment: This works for me in `knitr` 1.20.  Are you using that version?

Comment: I have version 1.20 too. And I'm using R 3.5.1. I even tried to include a call to `sub` around `x$message`, to no avail. I suspect `wrap.error` is not used. I'll update my initial question.

Comment: I was using R 3.4.4, and things have changed in R 3.5.1.  I've updated the answer.